# Set max column widths and have words wrapped (up to two lines)

Tags: css, bootstrap-table

I'm using the Bootstrap Table plugin:
https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table

I would like to specify each column max-width and if some content reaches that max-width it should wrap up to two lines, after that the content should be trimmed and displayed ending in "..."

I added this to the CSS of my tables:

```
.tabla>thead>tr>th,
.tabla>tbody>tr>th,
.tabla>tfoot>tr>th,
.tabla>thead>tr>td,
.tabla>tbody>tr>td,
.tabla>tfoot>tr>td {
    padding: 2px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.tabla{
    vertical-align: middle;  
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

It's displaying the columns trimmed ending in "..." but don't know how to achieve exactly what I need.

Comment: Please add snippet or live site link where we can see the exact result

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the text of the td tag in a span and give it a class name with property:

`word-break: break-word;`

**Example**

HTML:

`<td><span class="table-text">{{your text}}</span></td>`

CSS:

```
.tabla>thead>tr>th,
.tabla>tbody>tr>th,
.tabla>tfoot>tr>th,
.tabla>thead>tr>td,
.tabla>tbody>tr>td,
.tabla>tfoot>tr>td {
    padding: 2px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.tabla{
    vertical-align: middle;  
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.table-text { word-break: break-word; }
```

I don't have a device at hand to test the result, but the words in the span tag should wrap at the end of the column width and respect the td tag property.

Another idea would be just to have the `class="table-text"` for the inside span with these properties:

Without having a glimpse at your HTML code, it is hard to test it properly. But I managed to create this code snippet

```css
.table-text {
    margin: 2px;
    border: solid 2px blue;
    /* vertical-align: middle; */
    display: block;
    display: -webkit-box;
    /* Relates to display width */
     -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    /* Your line height */
    line-height: 1em;
    /* Double your line height
    for max-height to have 2 lines */
    max-height: 2em;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
 <div class="table-text">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
 </div>
```

Comment: Sorry, don't know how to achieve that with Bootstrap table

Comment: this will only break the sentences to the new line. How do you define when to show ellipsis ("...")?

Comment: @Divneet, I believe there was a -webkit property for that but I can't think of a way to do it in a pure CSS way. The second suggestion might work

Answer (score 0):

here is a mixin, if you are writing the stryles in scss, you can specify the max-width and the number of lines the text should wrap before giving and ellipsis("...")

```
    @mixin multiLineEllipsis($lineHeight: 1.2em, $lineCount: 1, $bgColor: white){
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        line-height: $lineHeight;
        max-height: $lineHeight * $lineCount; 
        text-align: justify;
        margin-right: -1em;
        padding-right: 1em;
        &:before {
          content: '...';
          position: absolute;
          right: 0;
          bottom: 0;
        }
        &:after {
          content: '';
          position: absolute;
          right: 0;
          width: 1em;
          height: 1em;
          margin-top: 0.2em;
          background: $bgColor;
        }
      }

  .multi-line-ellipsis {
    @include multiLineEllipsis($lineHeight: 1.2em, $lineCount: 2, $bgColor: white);  
  }
```

Just add the class multi-line-ellipsis to the rows of your bootstrap table.
Also you can change the variables $lineHeight: /*Line Height*/, $lineCount: /*No of line to wrap to before ellipsis(in your case, it is 2)*/, $bgColor: /*background Color*/